# What version of Crystal Reports is distributed with VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm trying to figure out what version of Crystal Reports I have. It's the one that comes in Visual Studio 2008. Does anyone know what it is or how can I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 Professional includes CR 2008 basic.

No CR with VS Basic or Express.

Check this [link](http://aspalliance.com/1564_What_Visual_Studio_Developers_Should_Know_About_Crystal_Reports_2008.2).

Answer (score 1):

According to the EULA [found in the default path] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Crystal Reports\license.txt, it's *CRYSTAL REPORTS BASIC FOR MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 2008*.  I'm pretty sure this is some variant of version 10.  As far as I'm aware, this is only included with the professional and team system versions.  It's not included in the basic version of Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Version is 10.5.3700. It is bundled with Visual Studio 2008 and different from Crystal Reports 2008, the standalone version. I can't offer much help other than that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full list according to [Which Crystal Reports assembly versions are supported in which versions of Visual Studio .NET](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Which+Crystal+Reports+assembly+versions+are+supported+in+which+versions+of+Visual+Studio+.NET):

```
 CR Product Name         CR Assembly Version   VS .NET Supported Version   CR Install Configuration                                                                                                                  
----------------------- --------------------- --------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 CR 9.1 for .NET 2002    9.1.3300.0            2002                        C:\Program Files\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\1.0\Bin                                                                                   
 CR 9.1 for .NET 2003    9.1.5000.0            2003                        C:\Program Files\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\1.0\Bin                                                                                   
 CR 9.2.x                9.2.3000.0            2002, 2003                  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\Bin                                                                                   
 CR 10.0.0.x             10.0.3300.0           2002, 2003                  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.5\Bin                                                                                   
 CR 10.2 for .NET 2005   10.2.3600.0           2005                        C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.7\Bin                                                                                          
 CR 10.5 for .NET 2008   10.5.3700.0           2008                        C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.8\bin                                                                                          
 CR 11.0.0.x             11.0.3300.0           2002, 2003                  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\3.0\Bin                                                                                   
 CR 11.5.0.x             11.5.3300.0           2002, 2003, 2005            C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin                                                                                          
 CR 12.0.0.x             12.0.1100.0           2002, 2003, 2005, 2008      C:\Program Files\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86                                                               
 CRVS2010                13.0.2000.0           2010                        C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86
```

Meaning for Visual Studio 2008, you're probably using Crystal Reports Version 10.5 or 12